# Can the Panel in Gnome 3 be hidden?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-panel

Is there a known way to hide the Panel in Gnome 3? I want it to be hidden by default, and visible only when I zoom out. The same way as with the workspaces and application icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [gnome-shell-extension-autohidetopbar](http://fpmurphy.com/gnome-shell-extensions) ([RPM](http://fedora.rasmil.dk/blog/?p=253)). Double-click the bar to enable autohiding.